# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package on installing ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ruamel.yaml

I get this error on installing the most recent ruamel.yaml with pip (Python 2.7):

```
File "/tmp/pip-build-jkyN5X/ruamel.yaml/util.py", line 10, in <module>

from .compat import text_type, binary_type

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

 ----------------------------------------
 Cleaning up...
```

Fixing the relative imports lead to import errors. What would be the proper fix?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with python2.7 and ruamel.yaml 0.11.7 (which was the latest version on 2016-03-12). Is this on Windows? Which version of pip? Is this as part of running `tox` or some other specific context)

Comment: Was some unknown pip/python error. Fixed on other installation